# Xcode Error: duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: xcode

I uploaded my unity game into Xcode and when I run it I get an error that I have never seen.

I have tried looking up solutions but none of them make it clear what to do.

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_UnityAdsUnityWrapperDelegate in:
    /Users/zach/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cpaqfqemlogukibygwijfynyrkvk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-58c342c17ccae78c42910554aa7fcfdcf0004ed65ee5ff27c27446ef2b86d435.o
    /Users/zach/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cpaqfqemlogukibygwijfynyrkvk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-58c342c17ccae78c42910554aa7fcfdc5bc1aa913d6c823342728edabfe58322.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_UnityAdsUnityWrapperDelegate in:
    /Users/zach/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cpaqfqemlogukibygwijfynyrkvk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-58c342c17ccae78c42910554aa7fcfdcf0004ed65ee5ff27c27446ef2b86d435.o
    /Users/zach/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cpaqfqemlogukibygwijfynyrkvk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-58c342c17ccae78c42910554aa7fcfdc5bc1aa913d6c823342728edabfe58322.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)